# PhpStorm MySQL connection how to check if query making full table scan

Tags: mysql, phpstorm, sql-execution-plan, datagrip

I have a test table with 660.000 rows with dummy books data. I'm trying to learn how index works etc.

But I have one problem: I just want to check if my query is making a full table scan. Is it possible to check it in PhpStorm?

Sample query:

```sql
explain ANALYZE select * from books where isbn = 9790085163660 limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can connect to the database from the SQL Console and issue commands manually from there (provided the user has the appropriate permissions of course).

Comment: You can also do some stuff via context menu: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-diagrams.html#creating-explain-query-plan